# MassTransit - Azure Functions / RabbitMQ - how to call into the consumer - and serialization question

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am trying MassTransit (8.0.15) and RabbitMQ (3.11.7) within an Azure Function (v4) App for local development on my box.

I am 'publishing' a message from a console app ... and I am able to hit the function app with the message fine.  But...

I am want to call into the 'consumer' class from within the Function and unable to locate an equivalent implementation of the IMessageReceiver / ServiceBusReceivedMessage.

Basically trying to do the following Azure Service bus code sample, but with RabbitMQ.

```
public class SubmitOrderFunctions
    {
        const string SubmitOrderQueueName = "submit-order";
        readonly IMessageReceiver _receiver;

        public SubmitOrderFunctions(IMessageReceiver receiver)
        {
            _receiver = receiver;
        }

        [FunctionName("SubmitOrder")]
        public Task SubmitOrderAsync([ServiceBusTrigger(SubmitOrderQueueName)] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return _receiver.HandleConsumer<SubmitOrderConsumer>(SubmitOrderQueueName, message, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Is there an equivalent implementation for RabbitMQ?  Or, should I be injecting the Consumer interface into function class and call the consumer that way?

My current implementation of the function - after some trial - looks like - needs the first *args* parameter for the *message* parameter to get serialized properly.  Without the first *args* parameter and if the second parameter is named anything different from the name *message*, the serialization would not work.  Basically, the properties with the TestMessage object are all being set to null and the *args* object has no properties initiazlized - indicating some issue with the way I have the serialization setup incorrectly.

Wondering what I am missing with this serialization issue?

```
[Function("TestFunction")]
        public void RunTestFunction([RabbitMQTrigger("test-queue", ConnectionStringSetting = "rabbitMQConnectionAppSetting")]
        BasicDeliverEventArgs args, TestMessage message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"TestFunction: C# Queue trigger function processed: {message?.id}/{message?.name}");
        }
```

Appreciate any pointers.

Thank you

Comment: MassTransit (at this point) only supports ASB/EventHub triggers for Azure Functions.